# Qt - ERROR: unknown module networkauth

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I am beginning developing with Qt and I have to make an application that connects to Spotify Web API. I tried to use Qt's Oauth module but I got the error shown on title.

I am using Qt Creator and Fedora 27. I have installed my system few days ago, so the packages should be the more recent ones.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you research the problem yourself and if so what did you find?  For example a Google search brings up this related post: https://forum.qt.io/topic/42811/qmake-error-unknown-module-s-in-qt-network-widgets-gui-core  

Did you first try building and running the Qt examples for Network Authorization?  See https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/examples-qtnetworkauth.html

Comment: You didn't mention which version of Qt you're using and where/when exactly this error is shown. Also, when replying to comments, use the @username syntax, otherwise people won't know you responded to them.

Comment: @BrianO'Donnell  
Yup. I have already seen these posts. I did what they said but hasn't worked for me :/

Comment: Thanks @NikosC. 
And i am using Qt 5.9 and the error is shown on build phase, when it runs make

Comment: Did you install Qt from the online installer or the Fedora package repository?

Answer (score 4):

Obviously, you have used `Qt Online Installer` because you are using such a new version of Qt. Because Qt Creator is not complaining about other modules you are just missing `Qt Network Auth component` (networkauth module) from your installation.

Qt Network Auth is not part of the basic Qt installation package but an add-on which you have to separately select in the online installer. Use the **Maintenance Tool** under your Qt install dir to **add Qt Network Auth (TP) component** to your installation (TP means Technology Preview). Run `qmake` again after you have added the missing module. After running qmake you can rebuild your application.

[image]
[image]